# Function call in golang channel

Tags: go

I've been trying to get a function to be called "inside" a golang channel (think pythons pool.apply_async, where I can queue a load of functions and run them concurrently later on). But to no avail. Everything I've read leads me to believe that this should be possible, but now I'm thinking it isn't, as I'm seeing compile error after error for anything I try. The code is below (should be self contained and runnable)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type NodeSettings struct {
    Timeout  int
    PanelInt float64
    PanelCCT float64
    SpotInt  float64
    SpotCCT  float64
    FadeTime int
    Port     int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Attempting comms with nodes")

    futures := make(chan func(ip string, intLevel, cctLevel int, ns *NodeSettings), 100)
    results := make(chan int, 100)

    ns := NodeSettings{
        Timeout:  5,
        PanelInt: 58.0,
        PanelCCT: 6800.0,
        SpotInt:  60.0,
        SpotCCT:  2000.0,
        FadeTime: 0,
        Port:     40056,
    }

    spots := []string{"192.168.52.62", ...snipped}

    panels := []string{"192.168.52.39", ...snipped}

    for _, ip := range panels {
        intLevel := math.Round(254.0 / 100.0 * ns.PanelInt)
        cctLevel := math.Round((7300.0 - ns.PanelCCT) / (7300.0 - 2800.0) * 254.0)
        fmt.Printf("IP %s was set to %d (=%d%%) and %d (=%d K)\n",
            ip, int(intLevel), int(ns.PanelInt), int(cctLevel), int(ns.PanelCCT))
        futures <- set6Sim(ip, int(intLevel), int(cctLevel), &ns)
    }

    for _, ip := range spots {
        intLevel := math.Round(254.0 / 100.0 * ns.SpotInt)
        cctLevel := math.Round((6500.0 - ns.SpotCCT) / (6500.0 - 1800.0) * 254.0)
        fmt.Printf("IP %s was set to %d (=%d%%) and %d (=%d K)\n",
            ip, int(intLevel), int(ns.SpotInt), int(cctLevel), int(ns.SpotCCT))
        futures <- set8Sim(ip, int(intLevel), int(cctLevel), &ns)
    }
    close(futures)

    fmt.Println("Complete")
}

func set6Sim(ip string, intLevel, cctLevel int, ns *NodeSettings) int {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Simulated (6) run for IP %s", ip))
    return 1
}

func set8Sim(ip string, intLevel, cctLevel int, ns *NodeSettings) int {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Simulated (8) run for IP %s", ip))
    return 1
}
```

Originally, my chan definition was `make(chan func(), 100)` which resulted in:

```
.\nodesWriteTest.go:52:11: cannot use set6Sim(ip, int(intLevel), int(cctLevel), &ns) (type int) as type func() in send
.\nodesWriteTest.go:60:11: cannot use set8Sim(ip, int(intLevel), int(cctLevel), &ns) (type int) as type func() in send
```

Which I assumed was due to the signature not matching, but alas, even with matching signatures I still get a similar error:

```
.\nodesWriteTest.go:51:11: cannot use set6Sim(ip, int(intLevel), int(cctLevel), &ns) (type int) as type func(string, int, int, *NodeSettings) in send
.\nodesWriteTest.go:59:11: cannot use set8Sim(ip, int(intLevel), int(cctLevel), &ns) (type int) as type func(string, int, int, *NodeSettings) in send
```

Starting to think that this isn't possible, so is there any other way to achieve the same thing? Or have I just not quite got it right. Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can send functions through channels. Note the "through" channels. You cannot do _anything_ to something inside a channel. The problem is that `set6Sim(...)` executes the function and the returned int cannot be sent on the channel. I have to admit I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do, so please come up with a _minimal_ example.

Comment: "I've been trying to get a function to be called inside a golang channel" -- this doesn't even make sense. A channel is essential a data structure. You can't call functions "inside" of data structures.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm new to channels, and thought they'd be more helpful. I've since replaced it with sync.WaitGroup which is more what I wanted in the first place, I just didn't know it. Usually SO is a little more insightful. Go tagged questions seem to be met with eliteism, and that's just not helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, what you're trying to do is send an `int` instead of an anonymous function `func()` since your `set6Sim` and `set8Sim` statements both return `int`s. This is why the compiler is throwing you that error.

Instead, you'll need to structure an anonymous function to be sent into the channel, like so:

```golang
    futures <- func(ip string, intLevel, cctLevel int, ns *NodeSettings) {
        set6Sim(ip, int(intLevel), int(cctLevel), ns)
    }
```

Your code is a bit hard to follow since we have no idea what you're trying to do. So without a minimal example, this will hopefully point you in the right direction with whatever you're trying to solve.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after thank you. I didn't think the code was that hard to follow. Just needed a function to be called, as in a worker pool type scenario. Thank you.